# URLEncodedUtils.format deprecated in Android

Tags: java, android, urlencode

`URLEncodedUtils` is deprecated. What could I use instead in this code? I need to change URLEncode.Utils.Format() line.

And **yParam** is this:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> yParam= new ArrayList<>();
```

Maybe I should use something different then ?
I am targeting API 23

```
public String construct() {
  return (iftrue? HOSTING_NAME : _NAME) + yDomain
         + (param.size() > 0 ? "?"
         + URLEncodedUtils.format(yParam, "utf-8") : "");
}
```

Comment: Yes, but there was no relevant answer given.

Comment: That's not a reason for creating duplicate questions